# Ifelse only returns first element of list

Tags: r

I have two lists:

```
list1<- list(x=c(1,2,3),
         y=c(4,5,6))
list1

#$x
#[1] 1 2 3

#$y
#[1] 4 5 6

list2<- list(x=c(1,2,3),
         y=c(4,5,6),
         z=c(7,8,9))
list2

#$x
#[1] 1 2 3

#$y
#[1] 4 5 6

#$z
#[1] 7 8 9
```

I am trying to do an `ifelse()` statement based on the lists' length, which should return the second list if its length is higher than the first list. However, the `ifelse()` statement only returns the first element of the desired list:

```
ifelse(length(list1)<length(list2),list2,list1)

# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Why does this happen, and how can I get the `ifelse()` statement to return the entire list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ifelse` is for vectors, use `if`/`else` for scalar comparisons.

```
if(length(list1)<length(list2)) list2 else list1

#$x
#[1] 1 2 3

#$y
#[1] 4 5 6

#$z
#[1] 7 8 9
```

`ifelse` returns output of same length as the test that we are performing. `length(length(list1)<length(list2))` is 1 hence the output from it is also of length 1.

Answer (score 2):

`ifelse` always returns an object of the same length as the condition. In this case, the condition `length(list1)<length(list2)` evaluates to a single logical. Because it is a single logical (length 1), the return is also of length 1, which happens to be the first element of the list.

`dplyr`'s `if_else` hints at this problem:

```
dplyr::if_else(length(list1)<length(list2),list2,list1)
Error: `true` must be length 1 (length of `condition`), not 3.
```

So the solution (as suggested above) is to use an if/else.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it's better to use non-vectorized version `if ... else ...` [as @Ronak Shah did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66762716/12158757).

---

However, if you insist on using `ifelse`, below might be one workaround

```
ifelse(length(list1)<length(list2),list(list2),list(list1))[[1]]
```

which gives

```
$x
[1] 1 2 3

$y
[1] 4 5 6

$z
[1] 7 8 9
```